# Calculate time when a moving ball hits a moving line

Tags: java, math, collision-detection, collision

I had a similar question but although I had the help of the community I couldn't solve it.

I have following problem:
A ball moves towards a moving line.
I want to know WHEN the ball collides with the line.

My best attempt to solve it:
[image]

All variables:
`f(x) ... The line of the ball movement`

`g(x) ... The line before it moved`

`g1(x) ... The line after it moved`

`g2(x) ... The line after it moved + the radius (when the ball center hits this line, the ball border hits g1(x)`

`A (Ax, Ay) ... First point of the line before it moved`

`A1 (A1x, A1y) ... First point of the line after it moved`

`B (Bx, By) ... Second point of the line before it moved`

`B1 (B1x, B1y) ... Second point of the line after it moved`

`Vc (Vcx, Vxy) ... Speed of ball`

`Va (Vax, Vay) ... Speed for point A`

`Vb (Vbx, Vby) ... Speed for point B`

`r ... Radius of the ball`

`t ... Time of collision`

1. I calculate A1 and B1

`A1 = (Ax + Vax * t, Ay + Vay * t)`

`B1 = (Bx + Vbx * t, By + Vby * t)`

2. I build the equation for g1(x)

`g1: y1 = k1 * x + d1` (`y = kx + d`)

`k1 = (B1y-A1y)/(B1x-A1x)` (`k = (dif between y)/(dif between x)`)

`d1 = A1y - k1 * A1x` (`d = y - kx`)

3. I build the equation for g2(x)

`g2: y2 = k1 * x + d2`

4. I calculate d2 using the distance equation between two parallel lines ([see wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_between_two_straight_lines)). I know the distance between g1(x) and g2(x) is the radius of the ball

`r = abs(d2 - d1)/sqrt(k1^2 + 1)`

5. I solve it for d2
6. I build the equation for f(x)

`f: y = k * x + d`

`k = Vcy/Vcx`

`d = Cy - k * Cx`

7. I calculate the intersection

`f(x) = g2(x)`

8. I solve it for t

Microsoft Mathematics and my TI Nspire CX CAS are able to calculate every step EXCEPT step 8

Is there a easier way to do it?

Or do you know any programs that should be able to solve it?

(My old question: [click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122963/calculate-time-when-a-moving-ball-collides-with-a-moving-line-polygon-2d))

Comment: One troubling aspect is what exactly do this `g1: y1 = k1 * x + d1 (y = kx + d)`  and this `k1 = (B1y-A1y)/(B1x-A1x) (k = (dif between y)/(dif between x))` mean mathematically? And it would be helpful to see the actual equation in terms of `t` for `f(x) = g2(x)`, among others.

Comment: I meant `y = mx + b`

I learned it like `y = kx + d`

So replace every k with m and d with b ^^

Comment: Oh. So `(y = kx + d)` is sort of a comment, as (now clearly) is `(k = (dif between y)/(dif between x))`. I understand. Didn't try hard enough to do so originally.

Comment: yes, for better understanding (but it didn't work, I guess)

Comment: I have Windows CAS called Derive, to which I'd like to give the `f(x) = g2(x)` equation. Not saying it can or will solve for `t`, but it would be quicker than the Nspire.

Comment: give me like 10 minutes than I can get you the whole equation for t

Comment: P.S. Nspire is driven by *Derive*, which was a brilliantly-developed, powerful CAS until TI bought it and took it off the market to sell more calculators that aren't *nearly* as powerful.

Comment: I was just advised to move to chat, but I doubt I have much more to add, so let's not.

Comment: `solve⁡((-(t v_ax+A_x ))  (t v_by-t v_ay+B_y-A_y )+r √((t v_by-t v_ay+B_y-A_y )^2+1)+x (t v_by-t v_ay+B_y-A_y )+t v_ay+A_y=(x v_y-C_x  v_y)/v_x +C_y,t)`

Comment: Derive chokes on `_`, so I deleted all and came up with an equation in terms of multi-letter variables--juxtaposition is NOT multiplication; SPACE is multiplication (so, for example, `vax` is a variable and `t vax` is "`t` times that variable"): `-(t vax+Ax )) (t vby-t vay+By-Ay )+r √((t vby-t vay+By-Ay )^2+1)+x (t vby-t vay+By-Ay )+t vay+Ay=(x vy-Cx vy)/vx +Cy`. If that captures the idea, it was able to solve for `t` and it's a horrendous mess that I'll post as an answer *IF* that equation is correct. And the mess suggests not.

Comment: The variables that Derive found in the equation are: `x, Ax, Ay, By, Cx, Cy, r, t, v, vax, vay, vby, vx, and vy`.

Comment: Found a little mistake. I will upload the correct version in 3 min, but it won't be easier ;)

Comment: Microsoft mathematics crashed... I have to reenter all equations...

Comment: `solve⁡((x v_y-c_x  v_y)/v_x +c_y=-((t v_ax+a_x )  (t v_by-t v_ay+b_y-a_y ))/(t v_bx-t v_ax+b_x-a_x )+t v_ay+(x (t v_by-t v_ay+b_y-a_y ))/(t v_bx-t v_ax+b_x-a_x )+√((t v_by-t v_ay+b_y-a_y )^2/(t v_bx-t v_ax+b_x-a_x )^2 +1)  r+a_y,t)`

Comment: that's the right one. and there will be a mess...

Answer (score 1):

Shucks. Derive has been working for a minute. It never comes back from such a trip. Is it possible there is still an error? Or that the equation can't be solved algebraically?

Here's the equation it was trying to solve (for two minutes):

[image]

Let's break it up:

Solve

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

for t.

I just remembered how to do subscripts, sort of:

[image]

[image]

Comment: unfortunately there are no errors... It's just a f**cking complicated equation. I am working for 2 days on it now...

Tomorrow I will ask my math professor and perhaps my physic teacher.
If I found the solution I will update my question!

A big thank you for your effort!!!

Comment: I wish you luck! I WOULD LOVE to see the result.

Comment: Just a little update: Mapel 17 calculates for 13 mins now and used 5,3 GB of my RAM already...

Comment: I think I have to find another way ^^

Comment: I reached the limits of my PC. Never thought that could happen... Mapel used 29.7/31.9 GB

Comment: I used "Wolfram Mathematica" and my old method (there is a link in the question)

But, the formula is "useless". I copied the whole equation into Word and... 157 pages. Way to complicated.